# startActivityForResult from adapter , onActivityResult inside the activity

Tags: android, kotlin

i have an adapter and i cast the context passed from `MainActivity`, here is the `Adapter` code

```
class Adapter {
....
....
inner class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    init {
       val intent = Intent((context as MainActivity), FooActivity::class.java)
       context.startActivityForResult(intent, FROM_FOO_ACTIVITY)
    }
}
```

then on the `FooActivity`

```
val intent = Intent()
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
finish()
```

then on the `MainActivity`

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == FROM_FOO_ACTIVITY) {
            //do my thing
        }
    }
```

the problem is it did not get to onActivityResult, what's wrong with my approach ?

Comment: Is your `requestCode` a positive integer value?

Comment: yes, FROM_FOO_ACTIVITY = 30

Comment: try with replacing context.startActivityForResult(intent, FROM_FOO_ACTIVITY) with (context as MainActivity).startActivityForResult(intent, FROM_FOO_ACTIVITY)